# How to read/write or iterate through a specific range of elements within a std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to read/write some specific range of memory within a bigger piece of memory, basically I would like to do something like this:

```
std::array<int, 1024> big_array;
unsigned short int offset = 128;

template<std::size_t SIZE>
void ReadArray(std::array<int, size>&  big_array_with_address_offset)
{
  // ... some code in here 
}

ReadArray(big_array + offset); //--> This doesn't work
```

I was able to do something similar for another function I was working on (code below) with raw pointers as function parameter, but I'm trying to do this in a modern C++(11 on wards) way since I need to use `std::array`. **I don't want to use raw pointers as function parameter**.

```
int FindMinElement(int * array)
{
    // Min element from range: 128 to 384
    return *std::min_element(array, array+256);
}

FindMinElements(big_array.data()+128);
```

**NOTE1**: The only way I was able to work with a smaller `std::array` in the function parameter is with `template<std::size_t SIZE>`, otherwise I get compilation errors due to the size incompatibility.

**NOTE2**: I don't want to do this with `std::vector` since I need static memory and not dynamic.

Comment: Use iterators.  They let you define a range from which to copy.  They also work with `std::copy` so you can use that to copy the elements from one array to the other.  This is almost a dupe of one of your previous questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431819/how-to-pass-stdarray-instance-address-as-parameter-to-stdmin-element

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (in C++20) might help, else pass iterators instead of container.

Comment: If you want to pass container, then pass also offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure this out, this is what I was trying to achieve and what I meant about using iterators and modern C++ withouth raw pointers, P.W. answer was close to what I wanted to achieve:

```
short int FindMinElement(std::array<short int, 1>::iterator it);
{
    // Min element from range: 128 to 384
    return *std::min_element(it, it + 128);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 1024> big_array{{0}}; 
    unsigned short int offset = 128;
    short int minval = 0;

    // Asuming big_array is populated in some other place before calling FindMin..()
    minval = FindMinElement(std::begin(big_array) + offset);
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to be able to manipulate data without using a raw pointer, then the solution was to use an iterator as parameter instead of a pointer.

This also solves the compilation error mentioned in NOTE1 that I had when passing a reference of a bigger std::array to a smaller std::array function parameter

Answer (score 2):

Pass the address of the array at the `offset` element to `FindMinElement` function. See below example on how to do it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

std::array<int, 1024> big_array;
unsigned short int offset = 128;

int FindMinElement(int *array)
{
    // Min element from range: 128 to 384
    return *std::min_element(array, array+256);
}

int main(void)
{  
    int counter = 0;
    for(auto & i : big_array) //populates the array from 0 to 1023
    {
        i = counter++; 
    }       
    cout << "Min element in the range 128 to 384 is: ";
    cout << FindMinElement(big_array.begin() + 128) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Min element in the range 128 to 384 is: 128
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but that is what I did, I mentioned that I don't to use this approach since it uses raw pointers, I want to use something a more modern C++ approach, like using iterators

Comment: In that case, you can use the `begin()` iterator of `std::array`. I have update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Send in an iterator to the beginning of the array instead of sending in the array.

Your FindMinElement function received a pointer, not really an array. Sending in an iterator is the closest equivalent.

Comment: Hi, I know it's receiving a pointer, that's what I said in the explanation, I was able to achieve the expected behavior using raw pointers but I want to do it with arrays and iterators like the first prototype